# Nuanced Excel Question; calculating proportions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Fellow overflowers, all help is appreciated;

I have the following rows of values (always 7 values per row) of data in Excel (3 examples below), where data is coded as 1 or 2. I am interested in the 1's.

2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.

1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2.

2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2.

I use the =MATCH(1,A1:G1,0) to tell me WHEN the first 1 appears, BUT now I want to calculate the proportion that 1's make up of the the remaining values in the row.

For example;

2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1. (1 first appears at point 3, but then 1's make up 2 out of 4 remaining points; 50%).

1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2. (1 first appears at point 1, but then 1's make up 1 out of the 6 remaining points; 16%).

2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2. (1 first appears at point 4, but then 1's make up 2 out of the 3 remaining points; 66%).

Please help me calculate this proportion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this one

```
=(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH(1,A1)+3,1000)," ",""),",",""))
-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH(1,A1)+3,1000)," ",""),",",""),1,""))
)/LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH(1,A1)+3,1000)," ",""),",",""))
```

The

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH(1,A1)+3,1000)," ",""),",","")
```

-part gets the string after the first `1`. The single `1` in the middle part is the one, you want to calculate the percentage for. So if you want to adapt the formula to other chars, you have to change the single `1` in th emiddle part and the three `1`s in the three `search`es.

[image]

EDIT thank you for the hint @foxfire
A solution for values in columns would be

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(A1:G1,1,MATCH(1,A1:G1,0)+1):G1,1)/(COUNT(A1:G1)-MATCH(1,A1:G1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: OP posted that the numbers are in different cells. *I use the =MATCH(1,A1:G1,0)* that means those 7 numbers are in range A:G (7 columns)

Comment: WOW, thank you so much for your help! Was a helpful response! Appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with SUMPRODUCT:

[image]

My formula in column H is a MATCH like yours:

```
=MATCH(1;A3:G3;0)
```

My formula for calculatin % of 1's over reamining numbers after first 1 found, is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:G3=1)*(COLUMN(A3:G3)>H3))/(7-H3)
```

This is how it works:

1. `(A3:G3=1)` will return an array of 1 and 0 if cell value is 1 or not. So for row 3 it would be `{0;0;1;0;0;1;1}`.
2. `COLUMN(A3:G3)>H3` will return an array of 1 and 0 if column number of cell is **higher** than column number of first 1 found, (that matchs with its position inside array). So for row 3 it would be `{0;0;0;1;1;1;1}`
3. We multiply both arrays. So for row 3 it would be `{0;0;1;0;0;1;1} * {0;0;0;1;1;1;1} = {0;0;0;0;0;1;1}`
4. With SUMPRODUCT we sum up the array of 1 and 0 from previous step. So for row 3 we would obtain `2`. That means there are 2 cells with value 1 after first 1 found.
5. `(7-H3)` will just return how many cells are after first 1 found, so fo row 3, it means there are 4 cells after first 1 found.
6. We divide value from step 4 by value from previous step, and that's the % you want. So for row 3, it would be `2/4=0,50`. That means 50%

**update:** I used 2 columns just in case you need to show where is the first 1. But in case you want a single column with the %, formula would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:G3=1)*(COLUMN(A3:G3)>MATCH(1;A3:G3;0)))/(7-MATCH(1;A3:G3;0))
```

Comment: Thank you to this response, I really appreciate the effort that both of you put into this, both really great solutions!